# How can I make collection page like unsplash in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, image-gallery

I am new to web development, trying to make a image gallery and I can't figure out how to make the collection page.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Please include what do you want to do, what have you tried in order to do that and hopefully, where or what error message are you receiving.

Only then, me or someone will be able to help you.

If you don't know how to start, you are in the wrong place.

You should start watching some tutorial on youtube, then read some documentation and help yourself with more tutorials.

When you have a specific question, you come here.

:)